# Creating a `collection.mutable.SortedSet` -- ambiguity in `map` method

Tags: scala, collections, set, mutable, implicit-conversion

I am trying to work around the lack of a `collection.mutable.SortedSet` which is what my skip list implementation would be. I am almost there:

```
import collection.{SortedSet => CSortedSet, SortedSetLike => CSortedSetLike}
import collection.mutable.{Set => MSet, SetLike => MSetLike}
import collection.generic.{MutableSetFactory, GenericCompanion}

object SkipList extends MutableSetFactory[SkipList] {
  def empty[A](implicit ord: Ordering[A]): SkipList[A] = ???
}

trait SkipList[A] extends MSet[A] with MSetLike[A, SkipList[A]] with CSortedSet[A]
  with CSortedSetLike[A, SkipList[A]] {

  override def empty: SkipList[A] = SkipList.empty[A](ordering)

  def rangeImpl(from: Option[A], until: Option[A]): SkipList[A] =
    throw new Exception("Unsupported operation")
}
```

Ok, this compiles. But unlike the immutable sorted set, where I can unambiguously do

```
case class Holder(i: Int) extends Ordered[Holder] {
  def compare(b: Holder) = i.compare(b.i)
}

def test1(iss: ISortedSet[Holder]) = iss.map(_.i)

test1(ISortedSet(Holder(4), Holder(77), Holder(-2))).toList
```

this fails for my mutable sorted set:

```
def test2(sl: SkipList[Holder]) = sl.map(_.i)
```

with

```
error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method canBuildFrom in object SortedSet of type [A](implicit ord: Ordering[A])scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.SortedSet.Coll,A,scala.collection.SortedSet[A]]
 and method canBuildFrom in object Set of type [A]=> scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.mutable.Set.Coll,A,scala.collection.mutable.Set[A]]
 match expected type scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[SkipList[Holder],Int,That]
           def test2( sl: SkipList[ Holder ]) = sl.map( _.i )    
                                                      ^
```

This is beyond my overview. Any clues as how to achieve what the immutable sorted set already does? Any chance I can remove this ambiguity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need to define a `canBuildFrom` method in object `SkipList`. While doing so is not required, the purpose of defining your own `canBuildFrom` is to ensure that inherited methods return the best possible type. Since you're mixing in a couple of traits, it's creates an ambiguity if you're not defining your own implicit `canBuildFrom`.

In your case, adding something like,

```
import collection.generic.{CanBuildFrom, MutableSetFactory}
import collection.mutable.{Set, SetLike}

object SkipList extends MutableSetFactory[SkipList] {

  implicit def canBuildFrom[A : Ordering]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, SkipList[A]] =
    new CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, SkipList[A]] {
      def apply(from: Coll) = newBuilder[A]
      def apply() = newBuilder[A]
    }
}

trait SkipList[A]
extends Set[A] with SetLike[A, SkipList[A]] {
   override def empty: SkipList[A] = SkipList.empty[A]
}
```

should do the trick.

Martin wrote up a nice document a few months ago on implementing custom collections in [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html#), which includes a [section on integrating new sets and maps](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl_6.html). While it's terribly difficult to find, it's a definitive resource if you're interested in building your own collections.

Comment: thanks, especially for the links. in the meantime, i came up with a similar solution (see below).

Comment: I still get the ambiguous implicit error with this solution. Does it work for you, Sciss and Heather?

Comment: Yep, I just simplified + cleaned it up and verified that it works on both 2.9.0.1 and 2.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

With the proper `implicit def canBuildFrom` it is possible. I removed any mixins from `SortedSet` now, because my actual implementation not only takes an `Ordering` but also another evidence parameter. So I re-added a few bits from `SortedSet`. The solution is:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.mutable.{Builder, Set => MSet, SetBuilder => MSetBuilder,
  SetLike => MSetLike}

object SkipList {
  def empty[A](implicit ord: Ordering[A]): SkipList[A] = ???

  private type CC[A] = SkipList[A]
  private type Coll = CC[_]

  implicit def canBuildFrom[A: Ordering]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, CC[A]] =
    new SkipListCanBuildFrom

  private class SkipListCanBuildFrom[A: Ordering]
    extends CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, CC[A]] {

    def apply(from: Coll) = newBuilder[A]
    def apply() = newBuilder[A]
  }

  def newBuilder[A: Ordering]: Builder[A, CC[A]] = new MSetBuilder(empty[A])
}

trait SkipList[A] extends MSet[A] with MSetLike[A, SkipList[A]] {
  override def empty: SkipList[A] = SkipList.empty[A](ordering)
  implicit def ordering: Ordering[A]
}
```

Test compiles (and works in the actual implementation which is omitted here for brevity):

```
case class Holder(i: Int)
def test2(sl: SkipList[Holder]): SkipList[Int] = sl.map(_.i + 1)
```

Comment: Funny, I still get the ambiguous implicit error with Scala 2.8.1/2.8.2. Are you using 2.9?